# Binding properties outside ListBox collection

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have a `ListBox` and it's bound to `MyObject.MyCollection`, how can I also get `MyObject.MyValue`?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObject.MyCollection}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyObject.MyValue}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
public class MyObject {
   public ObservableCollection<CollectionThing> MyCollection {get; set;}
   public string MyValue {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Relative source in the binding

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObject.MyCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyObject.MyValue,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```